Export public key by private key with `SecKeyCopyPublicKey` on macOS failed?
I've been creating a key pair on macOS by SecKeyCreateRandomKey.
According to Apple Document (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/generating-new-cryptographic-keys?language=objc), I store private key in keychain and export public key by SecKeyCopyPublicKey everytime.

You could add a kSecPublicKeyAttrs attribute to the attributes dictionary, specifying a distinct tag and keychain storage for the public key. However, it’s typically easier to store only the private key and then generate the public key from it when needed. That way you don’t need to keep track of another tag or clutter your keychain.

However, I found on few macOS, the exported public key is always null, so I have to create key pair again every time. Maybe I can store both private key and public key to solve this problem, but does it have some better solution?
Code to create key pair:
@autoreleasepool {
  const auto* application_tag =
      [@(identity.c_str()) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  NSMutableDictionary* attributes = [@{
    (id)kSecAttrKeyType : (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
    (id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits : @256,
    (id)kSecAttrAccessible : (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock,
    (id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs : @{
      (id)kSecAttrIsPermanent : @YES,
      (id)kSecAttrApplicationTag : application_tag,
      (id)kSecAttrAccessGroup : @(GetAccessGroup().c_str()),
    },
  } mutableCopy];

  CFErrorRef err = nullptr;
  SecKeyRef key =
      SecKeyCreateRandomKey((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, &err);
  if (err || !key) {
    if (error) {
      // handling error...
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

and simply use SecKeyCopyPublicKey to export public key
SecKeyRef pub_key = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(pvt_key_); // it is null ?


I don't think you would ever need to store you public key as a new one can be generated pretty easily now days. You can however as the documentation states store it in the keychain, you just have to write your own logic for it. I will say also I moved over to CryptoKit awhile ago and it has a steep learning curve, but it's quite a bit nicer. have a look at this sample code on storing keys https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/storing_cryptokit_keys_in_the_keychain

Also have a look at the secure enclave very nice stuff https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/secureenclave
